# Output not got. Sample input: 7 & {1,2,1,2,1,3,2} Sample output: 2. Find the total number of pairs possible

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The code is to find the total number of pairs in the given input. In the code below, Firstly sorted the array.
Second, To count the number of pairs.
Subtracted 1 from count and divided it by 2 to get the number of pairs.
But didn't get the output.

Sample Input: 7 & {1,2,1,2,1,3,2}
Sample Output: 2

Also my code doesn't work if the input has even number of items(just realised).

So, what changes do I have to do to get the output right?

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num, temp, initial = 0, count = 0, sum = 0, k = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of items");
        num = in .nextInt(); in .nextLine();
        int[] arr = new int[num];
        System.out.println("Enter " + num + " items");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            arr[i] = in .nextInt(); in .nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < num; j++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        //Counting number of pairs
        initial = arr[0]; //to store the searching key
        while (k < num) {
            count = 0;
            while (k < num - 1 && arr[k] == initial) {
                count++;
                k++;
            }
            if (k < num) {
                initial = arr[k];
            }
            sum = sum + ((count - 1) / 2);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question about this code?

Comment: I am not getting the output when I give the input.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: let me know if my code is proper

Comment: "So, what changes do I have to do to get the output right?" - what have you tried to resolve the problems? Java IDEs provide excellent debugging capabilities